# What kind of “deals” do music distribution companies like Spotify make with record labels to distribute their music?

Tags: music-business, spotify

I’ve read in many places that companies such as Spotify make deals with major record labels to distribute music that they own the rights to on their own platform (i.e. their music player), but I would like to know more about these deals; how they work, what exactly changes hands, etc.